# How to avoid printing a new line when the database is empty?

Tags: python, mysql

I have an SQL query; when it executes and the database is empty, it gives an `empty()`, and it prints a new line even after stripping `\r,\n`.

How can I prevent this?

```
# Prepare SQL query to get the gerrits from the database.
sql_get = """SELECT gerrit_id
            FROM gerrits.gerrit_submit_table
            where (SI='%s'
            and component='%s' and release_bit = '0' and picked_bit = '0')"""%(SI,component)

#print sql_get
rows = cursor.execute(sql_get)  
gerrits = cursor.fetchall() 
print "gerrits"
print gerrits -->prints ()


print' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n') --> #prints a new line even after stripping \r\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` by itself prints a new line. You can instead see if the line is empty before even calling `print`

Ex.

```
if gerrits:
    print ' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits)
```

This will only print when `gerrits` contains data to be printed. Otherwise nothing is printed.

OR

End the `print` statement with a comma to skip it printing a newline

Ex.

```
print 'my text to print',
```

Comment: I need pass this value to another python script...I need to pass some value in case it is empty..how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, which value? Do you want a new line to print, if the string is non empty?

Comment: I added `print ' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits),` it still prints a new line

Comment: Strange, that's documented functionality https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

Answer (score 0):

`print` is also available as a function, and you can specify an `end` character other than the default newline `\n`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

```
   print('mystring',sep='',end='')
```

Comment: I tried `print (' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits) ,sep='',end='')` ,it gives an error `    print (' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits) ,sep='',end='')
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user2125827 To use the print function in Python 2, you have to have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file.